# C# debug/intellisense for XML data file creation based on existing schema for data import application

Tags: c#, xml

I saw a few questions might be related to my question but I decide to ask because I do not have a clear how to approach this efficiently (and correctly). Because right now, I only create multiple strings and appending them to a file with `.xml` extension

**Problem:**

1. I have a database but I am not allowed to interact with this database directly but via provided application which only takes XML file ~~~> I must create this `data_entry.xml` file to recreate new record.
2. I understand the XML I need to create based on existing scheme so the data follow database structure ~~~>  `ImportSchema.xsd`
3. Right now, I am writing a small C# winform application to generate the `data_entry.xml` from user inputs so I can import data to database

~~~~> I believe there should be a better way because right now here is what I do

step 1: I look at the `ImportSchema.xsd` in XML Schema Explorer / Visual Studio for 1st attribute of the element

step 2: Come back to Visual C# IDE and program correct xml code for that element's attribute

step 1: I look at the `ImportSchema.xsd` in XML Schema Explorer/Visual Studio for 2nd attribute of that element

Step 2: Come back to Visual C# IDE.....

and repeat these 2 steps....

Step 3: run my program to have `data_entry.xml`

Step 4: import this `data_entry.xml` to database via provided application see what errors I receive

Step 5: repeat what I do in Step 1 and Step 2 based on errors I receive.
~~~> **there are a lot of errors** returns because I have no idea how to debug/setup some type of intellisense to see if I am making an error. Right now, I just blindly write a method to write strings and append to `xml` extension file.

- if I miss the `/` or `/>`
- if I miss an required attribute
- if I do something stupid

**Question:**

Is there any better way to do what I would like to achieve: *have a good xml which contains the correct format* with less work? Is there any way so I can debug/have some type of intellisense?

Code might not be important here but it may help to see what I did

```
        // Create the file.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(_filePath))
        {
            Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + Environment.NewLine
                                                          + "<Database" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
                                                          + " ExportDate=\"" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "\"" + Environment.NewLine
                                                          + " ExportTime=\""  + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "\"" + Environment.NewLine
                                                          + Environment.NewLine
                                                          + "/>"
                                                          );
            // Header
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
```

Edit 1: I found that I should at least use `XmlWriter class` instead of just write string and append string.

Edit 2: I found that I can generate the class from `xsd.exe` from  briantyler

Comment: Well, you can use the `xsd.exe` tool that comes with visual studio that will generate a c# class based on your xsd, then you can work with that class and serialize it using the xml serializer. That will generate xml that complies with the xsd.

Comment: :) thanks, feel like I am reborn

Comment: The best way of debugging the xml file is to open the file and look at data.  What I often do is use VS.  From menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then past XML into view.  You can add schemas.  Once the xml file is pasted a menu option XML will appear where you can added additional schemas.  Any errors will appear in the Error List like any compiler errors.